# magento rest API how get POST data

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api

I have this code on api2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<api2>
    <resource_groups>
        <custom_restapi translate="title" module="Custom_Restapi">
            <title>Custom Rest API</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
        </custom_restapi>
    </resource_groups>
    <resources>
        <custom_restapi translate="title" module="Custom_Restapi">
            <group>custom_restapi</group>
            <model>custom_restapi/api2_restapi</model>
            <title>Testing My Rest API</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <privileges>
                <admin>
                    <create>1</create>
                </admin>
            </privileges>
            <attributes  translate="" module="Custom_Restapi">
                <firstname>First Name</firstname>
                <lastname>Last Name</lastname>
                <email>Email</email>
                <password>Password</password>
            </attributes>
            <routes>
                <route>
                    <route>/googlesearch</route>
                    <action_type>collection</action_type>
                </route>
            </routes>
            <versions>1</versions>
        </custom_restapi>
    </resources>
</api2>
```

in my V1.php file i have this code

```
class Custom_Restapi_Model_Api2_Restapi_Rest_Admin_V1 extends 
Custom_Restapi_Model_Api2_Restapi
{

protected function _retrieveCollection($data)
{
   var_dump($data);
    exit;
}

public function _create($productData)
{ 
    return "tested 2";
}

}
```

in POSTMAN i send

[image]

[image]

How can i get my POST data?
How do I accept the request in _create , because I only accept in _retrieveCollection ,